# IE5 and IE9 compatability issue

Tags: javascript, xml, vbscript

I am trying to render the xml element using response.write() statement as below.But It is getting rendered as nested elements.

```
Response.Write("<MessageList><message name=\"ButtonNone\" value=\"[None]\"/><message name=\"ButtonCancel\" value=\"Cancel\" desc=\"Close this screen without saving changes you have made.\" width=\"200\" height=\"60\"/><message name=\"Platform_MemberId\" value=\"Member ID\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"Platform_UserMemberId\" value=\"User Member ID\"/><message name=\"Platform_Password\" value=\"Password\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"Platform_ClientPassword\" value=\"Client Password\"/><message name=\"Platform_ForgetLogin\" value=\"Forgot your ID or password?\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"Platform_Login\" value=\"Continue\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"Platform_WFGPageFirst\" value=\"First &lt;&lt;__arg1__&gt;&gt;\" desc=\"Display the first section of the list.\" width=\"200\" height=\"50\"/><message name=\"Platform_WFGPagePrev\" value=\"Previous &lt;&lt;__arg1__&gt;&gt;\" desc=\"Display the previous section of the list.\" width=\"200\" height=\"50\"/><message name=\"Platform_WFGPageNext\" value=\"Next &lt;&lt;__arg1__&gt;&gt;\" desc=\"Display the next section of the list.\" width=\"200\" height=\"50\"/><message name=\"CommonLabelOrgUnit\" value=\"Org Unit\" desc=\"Depending on your assigned security role, you may or may not be able to select all organizational units. If you do not have access to a specific organizational unit, but need access, please contact your system administrator.\" width=\"300\" height=\"105\"/><message name=\"CommonLabelRole\" value=\"Role\"/><message name=\"ButtonContinue\" value=\"Continue\" desc=\"Once the required information has been entered, click this button to go to the next step in the process.\" width=\"300\" height=\"60\"/><message name=\"prtAlertCannotLogin\" value=\"You are already logged in. You cannot log in twice from the same browser. To log in again, close and restart your browser.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginSelectOrg\" value=\"You must select a default organizational unit.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginSelectRole\" value=\"You must select a default role.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginInvSel\" value=\"Invalid selections, please continue...\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginUsername\" value=\"You must specify a username.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginPassword\" value=\"You must specify a password.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginUnsuccess\" value=\"Your logon was not successful. Please check your Member ID and Password, then re-enter them here to log in.\r\n\r\nNote: your Password is case sensitive. Be sure to enter each letter as it was entered when you opened the account, paying special attention to whether each letter is upper-case or lower-case.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginUnsuccessSh\" value=\"Your logon was not successful. Please check the Member ID and Password.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertTimeout\" value=\"Your session has expired or you have not logged in. \r\n\r\nPlease enter your Member ID and Password here to log in.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertChangePassword\" value=\"Please change your password.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginBlockout\" value=\"You have exceeded the number of allowed login attempts.  Please try again later.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginCancel\" value=\"Are you sure you want to cancel?\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"Platform_NoMatches\" value=\"[No Matches]\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtNoteInstorePC\" value=\"Note: You are logging in from an in-store PC.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginBUNotAllowed\" value=\"This PC has been registered for use in this business unit only.  You cannot log in from this PC because you do not have rights to work at this business unit.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginRoleNotAllowed\" value=\"Your assigned role(s) cannot be accessed from this remote location. You cannot log in from this PC.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtAlertLoginRoleNotAllowedThisOrg\" value=\"There is no message named 'prtAlertLoginRoleNotAllowedThisOrg'.\"/><message name=\"prtSaveDefault\" value=\"Remember selections\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"prtLanguageLogin\" value=\"Language\" desc=\"Select the language to use for this session\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/><message name=\"ptFrmInvalidUserRole\" value=\"The Role selected is not an authorized User Role that is assigned to the logged in user.\" width=\"300\" height=\"100\"/></MessageList>");
```

Actual :

```
<MessageList>
<message name="ButtonNone" value="[None]"/>
<message name="ButtonCancel" value="Cancel" desc="Close this screen without 
     saving changes you have made." width="200" height="60"/>
<message name="Platform_MemberId" value="Member ID" width="300" 
     height="100"/>
..
..
</MessageList>
```

After rendering on IE11 and chrome

```
<messagelist>
     <message name="ButtonNone" value="[None]">
        <message height="60" width="200" name="ButtonCancel" value="Cancel" 
           desc="Close this screen without saving changes you have made.">
            ..
            ..
        </message>
     </message>
</messagelist>
```

If I set the response content type to XML,then it is displaying as properly but as a xml. But i want this to be rendered as HTML document.

**NOTE:** This perfectly works on IE 5. This is actually part of XML Island but as IE 9+ doesn't have support, so am looking for the possibilities to make it work on new browsers.

Can any one point me to the right direction to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IE5? The *twenty year old* browser?

Comment: IE5????????????

Comment: Wow - do you realise just how old IE5-IE9 are?  Why on earth do you still need to support them?

Comment: Chances are you need to send a `Content-Type: text/html` header or something, but that you even *have* IE5 to test with is kinda terrifying. Even IE9 is years out of support now.

Comment: Re: XML islands, they're deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla "HTML5 has a more general feature called "data blocks" that can carry almost any textual data, including XML."

Comment: Sadly this happens in the real world: sometimes even when you push back until you're blue in the face, a company will *still* demand IE5 support.  Not the OP's fault.

Comment: Unfortunately we have a legacy product. Need to support for new browsers now. They way it is working now is using quirks mode set to IE5.

Comment: am doing R&D where i embed this old website into new application through Iframe. But the new application runs under IE11. that is where hell lot of rendering issues were coming up.

Comment: @ChandraMohan Having been asked to do insane things at times myself, sometimes the right answer is "this can't be done, and trying to do it will cost more than a full rewrite/upgrade of the legacy application". You may be in this scenario.

Comment: @ceejayoz  am almost there :)

Comment: @ceejayoz but am wondering Even if i run the above Message List on chrome latest version, am getting as a nested elements. Is there some thing , am missing?

Comment: @ChandraMohan — Your XML is not HTML. Your content-type tells the browser it **is** HTML. (i.e. **You are lying**) The browser is trying to parse it as HTML. Error recovery treats `<message name="ButtonNone" value="[None]"/>` as "Start tag for the unknown element `message`". The `/` at the end has no special meaning.

Comment: Looks like it's treated as HTML (which makes sense, given the content type), so it probably doesn't deal well with the self-closing tags for that reason. (edit- what Quentin says right above). As a potential solution: Can you try to write a full, empty tag, like `<message name="" value=""></message>`, instead of just the self-closing tag?

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to set the [content type to XHTML](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/xhtml-mimetype/), although that probably also won't work well with IE5 and IE6.